# Access like tool for MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am looking for a tool to work with MySQL database. In particular, I am interested in a tool that has the same "Subdatasheet" feature as in MS Access. This functionality, basically joins table and shows them like a tree and it is easy to edit any value.

I looked at some posts here, and had a look at SQLYog. Any other alternative with subdatasheet feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Base](http://www.openoffice.org/product/base.html) (Open Office), it can also connect to a MySQL database.

Answer (score 3):

How about MS Access? You can connect it to other databases, including MySQL and we know you already like it.

Comment: Then there is all that reporting simplicity. And the run time is free.

Comment: Also, if you have been influenced by negative publicity, do not forget there are plenty of very respectable people who find Access, done properly, very useful.

Comment: @Remou - I think you are preaching to the choir. The OP seems to like Access already.

Comment: But I suspect the OP of having Doubts :)